# How to fill excel column using if condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have 3 columns in excel sheet.Let it be A B C. In A column it contain some values Y,Y,Y,N,N,Y..... similarly in B column it has values like Y,N,Y,Y.....

My aim is to fill column C using condition If A Contains Y and B contains Y then C will be S1,S2. If A Contains Y and B Contains N then C will be S1. If A contains N and B contains Y then c will be s2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
=IF(A1="Y",IF(B1="Y","S1,S2","S1"),IF(B1="Y","S2",""))
```

[image]

Comment: In this example, for each row i need to right the formula. How can i right a common formula for all row. Because i have 13000 rows. i cant right the formula for each.

Comment: @soumyaranjanpanda - Write formula in `Cell C2` and drag or copy it down till 13000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

copy this function to C1 and drag the bottom right corner of that tab through the C column till there are entries in A and B!

**`=IF(AND(A1="y" , B1="y"),S1 & " " &S2,IF(AND(A1="y" , B1="n"),S1,IF(AND(A1="n" , B1="y"),S2 )`**

change the parameters as required...

hope this helped you!